Is there an HDMI voice-activated device that can play Spotify?
I have an older sound system in my living room and I'm looking for a voice activated spotify player that wont require me to have my TV on or use my phone. I want to de-screen as much as possible and I just want to play music by voice activation. I have spotify premium if that helps. Otherwise I'll just buy an echo which will work but I wont be able to use my existing sound system.

what kind of system is that you have that is outdated ? I have a few suggestions but nothing like what your specifically asking for, but would still achieve the same end results and possibly cheaper.

Definitely gonna need more information on what sound system you have. An Echo Dot is probably a decent move, but we'll need more info.

These are some things I could find, not exactly what you were looking for but these might be a solution.

HDMI Audio Extractor: While not a dedicated Spotify device, an HDMI audio extractor can help. You can connect your HDMI source (such as a streaming device or gaming console) to the extractor, which then splits the audio signal. One output can go to your TV, and the other can connect to your sound system. You can control Spotify on your streaming device (e.g., Roku, Apple TV) and have the audio play through your sound system.

Smart TV Apps: Some smart TVs have built-in Spotify apps. If your TV supports Spotify, you can use voice commands through your TV's remote control to play music. While this doesn't directly involve HDMI, it achieves the same result.

Voice-Controlled Streaming Devices: Consider using voice-controlled streaming devices (like Amazon Echo or Google Nest) alongside your existing sound system. These devices can play Spotify and connect wirelessly to your speakers.

Bluetooth Audio Receivers: If your sound system has Bluetooth capabilities, you can pair your phone or tablet (which has the Spotify app) with a Bluetooth audio receiver. This way, you can control Spotify using voice commands on your device.



Nothing worth the price. But it may be easier for you to get an optical to  Bluetooth adaptor for the system instead.
You then just add the system as a "Bluetooth speaker" for whatever voice activated device you choose.
